# Get Text of checkbox with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="PrePayment">Pre-Payment<br />
```

How would I get the text "Pre-Payment" from this using Jquery?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give more information about the context? Before we can get anything from your element, we have to find it with a selector, and for that we will need to have an id or more information about your project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should probably have a value attribute in the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="PrePayment" value="Pre-Payment">Pre-Payment<br />
```

Then you can simply use the attr command:

```
$(input).attr('value');
```

Comment: Yeah I guess I'll just do that.

Comment: @downed: Value is often *not* the same as the text value. The answer will depend on whether they want the Text or the Value (and they initially said the Text).

Comment: Not Useful Answer. As @TrueBlueAussie says Text and value of the checkbox may not be the same.

Comment: What would I do if I want the text? Like @downed said, value and text are different many times

Answer (score 51):

I'd recommend putting the text inside a `<label>` tag so that you could click on it (and so that screen readers and such could make sense of your form):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="PrePayment" id="pre-payment">
<label for="pre-payment">Pre-Payment</label>
<br />
```

Then, the whole thing becomes easy:

```
var text    = $('label[for=pre-payment]').text();
var or_this = $('#pre-payment').next('label').text();
```

I'd prefer the first option, `label[for=...]`, as it is less fragile than the second

Comment: This is clearly the most correct way.  Anything else seems like a hack.

Comment: @mu is too short    how to call multiple check box text  like Ex:  cloth,men,jeanse

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Depends what the checkboxes look like but general you'd start with a selector that finds what you're interested in and then iterate over  `$(your_selector)`.

Answer (score 26):

Maybe:

```
$("input[name='PrePayment']")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue;
```

[**Try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/uu5RE/)

Comment: +1: `nextSibling.nodeValue` was just what I needed. I could not get `next()` to work with a filtered collection of checkboxes.

Comment: Maybe not the cleanest, but surely the easiest

Answer (score 2):

Check the below example and you get the script how to get label of checkbox in jQuery

```
<html>
 <body>
     <ul>
         <li>
             <input type="checkbox" name="mouse" value="1" id="mouse"  /><label for="mouse">Mouse</label>
            </li>
            <li>
             <input type="checkbox" name="keyboard" value="1" id="keyboard"  /><label for="mouse">Keyboard</label>
            </li>
            <li>
             <input type="checkbox" name="monitor" value="1" id="monitor"  /><label for="mouse">Monitor</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var label = jQuery('label[for=' + jQuery(this).attr('id') + ']').html();
 alert(label);
</script>
```

Code taken from this link : http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2015/09/how-to-get-checkbox-label-text-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this - another way you could make this work (with HTML5) is to use data attributes.

As an example, you'd set a data attribute as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="PrePayment" data-text="Pre-Payment">Pre-Payment<br />
```

You could then read this data attribute by using the following jQuery:

```
$(input).data('text');
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that you can have a seperate value parameter if required.